# removing nulls in case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to return the current Monday along with previous monday's data. I want to roll up my nulls or 0000 to have one record return.

```
select 
    da.Customer,
    sum(case 
           when DAteadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, Getdate()), 1) = d.FullDate           
              then (da.[USD - Balance])
              else 0 
        end) as MondayofCurrentWeek,
    sum(case 
           when DAteadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, Getdate() - 7), 1) = d.FullDate  
              then (da.[USD - Balance])
              else 0
        end) as PreviousMonday
from 
    Dataset_DemandArchive da 
inner join 
    Dimdate d on d.DateNameUS = da.CREDAT_0
where 
    da.CREDAT_0 in (dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, Getdate()), 1),
                    dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, Getdate() - 7), 1))
group by 
    Customer, FullDate 
order by 
    1
```

[image]

Comment: Is the image showing the data you're getting, or the data you want to get? If it shows the data you're getting, please show the data you want to get instead too.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: Try removing `FullDate` from `GROUP BY`

Comment: the image above is the data I am getting. I would like to rollup the zero's and return one record for each customer.

Comment: Again: remove the `FullDate` from `GROUP BY`, those are two different dates, current and previous week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use window functions?

```
select da.*
from (select da.Customer, d.FullDate,
             sum(da.[USD - Balance]) as MondayCurrentWeek
             lag(sum(da.[USD - Balance]), 7) over (partition by da.Customer order by d.FullDate)
      from Dataset_DemandArchive da join
           Dimdate d
           on d.DateNameUS = da.CREDAT_0
      group by Customer, FullDate 
    ) da
where da.CREDAT_0 = dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, Getdate()), 1)
```

Comment: That increase my results and I am trying to return just on record. Can I roll up the zero or nulls in my previous screen shot.